# Is hosting your own website safe?

Tags: network, wifi, python, web-hosting

So I made this website on python with Flask. I want to host this website on a rasberry pi on my own home network which everybody in my family uses.

Should I?

Is it safe?

Comment: It depends; what's your risk tolerance? Are you familiar with developing secure web applications and auditing them?

Comment: First question's answer : My risk tolerance is that i dont want anyone to gain access to my internal wifi network and I dont want any of my or my family's devices(including the raspberry pi) to get compromised.

Second question's answer : Nope.

Comment: "Is it safe?" - Safe from what?

Comment: from getting compromised or compromising my wifi network or my family's devices

Comment: In short: unless specifically designed to withstand cross-origin attacks like CSRF it is not safe.